# Angular custom form control with emitEvent = false

Tags: angular

With the following code:

```
this.myCustomFormControl.setValue('a value', { emitEvent: false });
```

is it possible to get the `emitEvent` value in my custom form control's `writeValue` method?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-custom-form-control',
  ...,
  providers: [{
    provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
    useExisting: MyCustomFormControl,
    multi: true
  }]
})
export class MyCustomFormControl implements ControlValueAccessor {
  ...
  writeValue(value: string) {
    // is it possible to access emitEvent here?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, the emitEvent option is specific to the setValue method of the FormControl class. It allows you to determine whether the value change event should be emitted when programmatically setting the value of the control using setValue.

However, when working with a custom form control and implementing the writeValue method, direct access to the emitEvent option is not available. The purpose of the writeValue method is to update the form control's value when it receives a new value from the parent form. It does not have an equivalent option to control event emission.

If you need to control the emission of value change events when updating the value within the writeValue method of your custom form control, you would typically handle that logic separately. You can manually trigger event emission using the appropriate methods or emit a custom event to notify the parent form or any required components.

Remember that the writeValue method is primarily intended for internal value updates, and it is up to you to decide how to handle event emission or notifications outside of this method.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It sounds like the options parameter on the `setValue` method doesn't work for custom form controls?

Comment: @Antediluvian The options parameter is specific to Angular's built-in form controls and is not propagated to custom form controls. Therefore, the emitEvent option cannot be accessed directly in the writeValue method of your custom form control.